# Best way to show new notifications

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a system where there is a notification section with an icon where I have to high light that icon if new notification arrive. The first solution I wanted to use was `DOMNodeInserted` to the container div of the notification pane. But that method is deprecated. The second option is to implement a timer which checks whether the dom count is increase and according to that highlight the icon.

Is there a better way to implement this scenario using JavaScript.

Comment: Do you not have access to the notification event when it  occurs?

Comment: I actually develop the front end section where I will have to listen to the modification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That event was deprecated in favor of Mutation Observers which is supported by all modern browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One little question I have is do I need to disconnect the observer at some time since I want it to observe until the user goes away from the page!

Comment: Nope! That's just optional in the case that you don't want the observer running for performance reasons.